# Drop down Check boxes are not scrolling properly in IE 8 compatibility Mode

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, css

Hi I'm using user defined Drop down check box control in asp.net. When ever I scroll the application these drop down check boxes are not scrolling properly means if if scroll down they are not moving with all other controls. The drop down check boxes which i'm using is as follows:

```
 <IH:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="ddcbAlertAssignmentAlertStatus" runat="server"    AddJQueryReference="False"
                                                    CssClass="" DataSourceID="odsAlertAssignmentAlertStatus" DataTextField="AlertStatusName"
                                                    DataValueField="AlertStatusName" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cblAlertAssignmentAlertStatus_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" UseButtons="True" UseSelectAllNode="True" AutoPostBack="True">
                                                    <Style DropDownBoxBoxHeight="" DropDownBoxBoxWidth="100%" SelectBoxWidth="60%"
                                                        SelectBoxCssClass="DropDownZIndex2" />
                                                    <Texts SelectAllNode="Select all" SelectBoxCaption="Select Alert Status" />
```

and the css style class is

```
  .DropDownZIndex2
{
    position:relative;
    border-style: solid;
    z-index: 300 !important;
    background-color: #FFFF00;

}
```

like this i'm using 4 drop down list boxes whose z-indexes are 400,300,200 and 100 and these are present one below other and while i'm scrolling they are not moving up with all other controls and when i place my mouse on them they are jumping like moving up and down. I tried using different position properties like fixed relative etc but those didn't work. Each drop down check box is declared in one td tag of a table. The structure of my aspx is like this there is table in which in one td there is div with z-index 800 and inside this div there is a table in which the above mentioned drop down checkboxes are defined whose z-indexes are specified as mentioned. IT IS WORKING PROPERLY WHEN I RUN IT ON IE 8 ON NORMAL MODE BUT WHEN I RUN IT ON COMPATIBILITY VIEW THEN IT'S GIVING THE ABOVE PROBLEM. Please help me with this

Comment: Could you provide us with an JSFiddle of the HTML output? For now I can say that position: relative will not work inside a table, but .. a demo is appreciated.

Comment: I cannot provide demo because this is a part of big project

Comment: I don't have to see everything, but just show us the part that is not working as expected. The less code you provide us, the easier it will be to help you with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that a wrapper element may have its **Display** CSS property set to **Fixed**.

Quote: "An element with fixed position is positioned relative to the browser window. It will not move even if the window is scrolled."

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp